# jQuery .data() is being overwritten

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I currently have the following code for a jQuery tooltip plugin I am writing.  I am storing the config for each tooltip with jQuery's .data() method.  However, when I go to retrieve the data it has been overwritten by the most recently stored data from a completely different selector.  I can't figure out the issue as it was working prior and then suddenly stopped.  The main areas to look in are the addTooltip(), removeTooltip(), and displayTooltip().

Example:

```
$('#tooltip1').addTooltip('tooltip', { 'direction': 'bottom' });
$('#tooltip2').addTooltip('tooltip', { 'direction': 'left' });
```

In the above example I am selecting two completely different elements however when I display the #tooltip1 tooltip it will be using #tooltip2's config which in this case is 'direction': 'left'.

Any help is appreciated.

```
(function($) {

// Used as a template for addTooltip()
var tooltipDefaults = {
    'class': null,
    'showOn': 'mouseenter',
    'hideOn': 'mouseleave',
    'direction': 'top',
    'offset': 0
}

// Store generated IDs to avoid conflicting IDs
var tooltipIds = new Array();

// Keep track of displayed popups
var displayedTooltips = new Array();

function generateUniqueId()
{
    var id;

    do {
        id = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    } while ($.inArray(id, tooltipIds) !== -1);

    tooltipIds.push(id);
    return id;
}

function getUniqueId(id)
{
    return parseInt(id.substr(0, 5));
}

function isUniqueId(id)
{
    return !NaN(getUniqueId(id));
}

function removeUniqueId(id)
{
        var id = getUniqueId(id);

        var idIndex = $.inArray(id, tooltipIds);

        if (idIndex !== -1) {
            tooltipIds.splice(idIndex);
        }
}

$.fn.displayTooltip = function()
{
    var element = $(this);
    var tooltip = $('#' + element.attr('data-tooltip-id'));
    var config = element.data('config');

    var offset = element.offset();

    var left;   
    var top;

    switch (config.direction) {
        case 'left':
            top = offset.top + "px";
            left = offset.left - tooltip.outerWidth() - config.offset + "px";
            break;
        case 'top':
            top = offset.top - element.outerHeight() - config.offset + "px";
            left = offset.left + ((element.outerWidth() / 2) - (tooltip.outerWidth() / 2)) + "px";
            break;
        case 'right':
            top = offset.top + "px";
            left = offset.left + element.outerWidth() + config.offset + "px";
            break;
        case 'bottom':
            top = offset.top + element.outerHeight() + config.offset + "px";
            left = offset.left + ((element.outerWidth() / 2) - (tooltip.outerWidth() / 2)) + "px";
            break;
    }

    tooltip.css({
        'position': 'absolute',
        'left': left,
        'top': top,
        'z-index': 5000
    });

    if (element.isTooltipDisplayed()) {
        return;
    }

    tooltip.show();
    displayedTooltips.push(element.attr('id'));
}

$.fn.hideTooltip = function()
{
    var element = $(this);

    var idIndex = $.inArray(element.attr('id'), displayedTooltips);

    if (idIndex !== -1) {
        displayedTooltips.splice(idIndex);
    }

    $('#' + element.attr('data-tooltip-id')).hide();
}

$.fn.addTooltip = function(content, params)
{
    var config = $.extend(tooltipDefaults, params);

    return this.each(function() {
        var element = $(this);

        // If the element already has a tooltip change the content inside of it
        if (element.hasTooltip()) {
            $('#' + element.attr('data-tooltip-id')).html(content);
            return;
        }

        var tooltipId = (element.is('[id]') ? element.attr('id') : generateUniqueId()) + '-tooltip';
        element.attr('data-tooltip-id', tooltipId);

        var tooltip = $('<div>', {
            id: tooltipId,
            role: 'tooltip',
            class: config.class
        }).html(content);

        $('body').append(tooltip);

        /**
         * If showOn and hideOn are the same events bind a toggle
         * listener else bind the individual listeners
         */
        if (config.showOn === config.hideOn) {
            element.on(config.showOn, function() {
                if (!element.isTooltipDisplayed()) {
                    element.displayTooltip();
                } else {
                    element.hideTooltip();
                }
            });
        } else {
            element.on(config.showOn, function() {
                element.displayTooltip();
            }).on(config.hideOn, function() {
                element.hideTooltip();
            });
        }

        // Store config for other functions use
        element.data('config', config);

        // Saftey check incase the element recieved focus from the code running above
        element.hideTooltip();
    });
}

$.fn.hasTooltip = function()
{
    return $(this).is('[data-tooltip-id]');
}

$.fn.isTooltipDisplayed = function()
{
    var element = $(this);

    if (!element.hasTooltip()) {
        return false;
    }

    return ($.inArray(element.attr('id'), displayedTooltips) === -1) ? false : true;
}

$.fn.removeTooltip= function()
{
    return this.each(function() {
        var element = $(this);
        var tooltipId = element.attr('data-tooltip-id');
        var config = element.data('config');

        $('#' + tooltipId).remove();

        if (isUniqueId(tooltpId)) {
            removeUniqueId(tooltipId);
        }

        element.removeAttr('data-tooltip-id');

        if (config.showOn === config.hideOn) {
            element.off(config.showOn);
        } else {
            element.off(config.showOn);
            element.off(config.hideOn);
        }

        element.removeData('config');
    });
}

// Reposition tooltip on window resize
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (displayedTooltips.length < 1) {
        return;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < displayedTooltips.length; i++) {
        $('#' + displayedTooltips[i]).displayTooltip();
        console.log(displayedTooltips);
    }
});
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
element.data('config', config);
```

`config` will be prone to unwanted modification whenever we call:

```
 var config = $.extend(tooltipDefaults, params);
```

An example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/j8v4s/1/

You can solve this by creating a new object that inherits from tooltipDefaults but when modified, only itself will be changed. You can make your tooltipDefaults object a constructor like so:

```
function TooltipDefaults() {
    this.class = null;
    this.showOn = 'mouseenter';
    this.hideOn = 'mouseleave';
    this.direction = 'top';
    this.offset = 0;
}
```

Now we can just do this:

```
var config = new TooltipDefaults();
$.extend(config, params);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sXSFy/4/

And here's a working example of your plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/DWtL5/2/

Answer (score 0):

put the declaration of config inside the each loop

```
return this.each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var config = $.extend(tooltipDefaults, params);
    ...
```

otherwise the config in each of the elements data is going to reference that single config object, and when you change it the changes will be seen by each of the references.

You can also use the extend method again to make a clone of the config

```
var defConfig = $.extend(tooltipDefaults, params);

return this.each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var config = $.extend({}, defConfig);
```

Comment: I tried this out and it didn't fix the problem.  I also updated my explanation to a more clear version of the exact problem if you can glance at it again.